# How to restore changes after exporting?

Tags: python, export

Before exporting to FBX I modify the object's name, location, parent, etc.

All the exporting happens in a for loop of selected objects.

So I need to restore it after every export.

Example script:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
import os
import random


filepath = "C:/Users/karan/Desktop/"

override = context.copy()


for object in context.selected_objects:
    # It's a simple modification, but I will have some complex modifications.
    object.location = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
    
    # export
    override['selected_objects'] = [object]
    with context.temp_override(**override):
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=os.path.join(filepath, f"{object.name}.fbx"), check_existing=False, use_selection=True)
        
    # restore
    bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()
```

I get this error

`ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Object has been removed`

How to fix this?

And how to add a progress bar while exporting?

[image]

```
import bpy
import os
import random


class EXPORT_OT_export_fbx(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "export.fbx"
    bl_label = "Export FBX"


    def execute(self, context):
        filepath = "C:/Users/karan/Desktop/"
        names = [obj.name for obj in context.selected_objects]

        for name in names:
            object = bpy.data.objects[name]
            object.location = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())

            override = bpy.context.copy()
            override['selected_objects'] = [object]
            with context.temp_override(**override):
                bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=os.path.join(filepath, f"{object.name}.fbx"), use_selection=True)

            # restore
            bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()

        return {'FINISHED'}
    

class EXPORT_PT_export_fbx(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Export"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Export"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        if context.scene.export_progress >= 0:
            layout.enabled = False
            layout.prop(context.scene, 'export_progress', slider=True)
        else:
            layout.operator("export.fbx")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(EXPORT_OT_export_fbx)
    bpy.utils.register_class(EXPORT_PT_export_fbx)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.export_progress = bpy.props.IntProperty(name = 'Exporting...', subtype = 'PERCENTAGE', min = -1, soft_min = 0, soft_max = 100, max = 100, default = -1)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(EXPORT_OT_export_fbx)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(EXPORT_PT_export_fbx)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.export_progress


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: After restore, you will get ReferenceError on some pointer, see:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268787/how-does-the-undo-operation-work/268869#268869

Comment: I don't want to use the undo system.

Comment: This post can explain why the ReferneceError occurs, so just put `object = bpy.data.objects.get('Cube')` in the forloop to fix that. `override` also need.

Comment: I want to loop over `context.selected_objects`, I updated my question.

Comment: @XY how to add progress bar while exporting?

Comment: I know there are two methods, the panel method and the blf method. I only know the blf method. For the panel method, you can see this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/how-to-show-to-the-user-a-progression-in-a-script  
The panel method may not work because you restore the file every time.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how to implement it in my script.

Comment: It is hard and tricky for both method because when you restore the file, it restore everything, like operator model, panel, some handler... If you want to do the blf method, I can try to help you, but I'm going out now, and you need to wait until I'm free.

Comment: Yeah, I will wait until you are free, I don't want the `blf` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, if not tell me I'll fix it

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
import os
import random


filepath = "C:/Users/karan/Desktop/"
names = [obj.name for obj in context.selected_objects]

for name in names:
    object = bpy.data.objects[name]
    object.name += ".fbx"
    object.location = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())

    override = bpy.context.copy()
    override['selected_objects'] = [object]
    with context.temp_override(**override):
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=os.path.join(filepath, object.name), check_existing=False, use_selection=True)

    # restore
    bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()
```

---

To show the progress after reloading the blend file, you can refer to this

```
import bpy
import os
import random
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

is_button_press = [False]
data = {}

@persistent
def when_new_file(dummy):
    print("new file detected")
    do_job()

def init_job():
    print("init job")
    data["job_ind"] = 0
    data["job_ind_end"] = 100
    bpy.context.scene.export_progress = 0
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(when_new_file)
    bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()

def do_job():
    print("do_job, ind= ", data["job_ind"])
    # do something you want here

    if data["job_ind"] == data["job_ind_end"]:
        end_job()
    else:
        bpy.app.timers.register(next_job)

def next_job():
    data["job_ind"] += 1
    bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()
    if "job_ind" in data:
        bpy.context.scene.export_progress = data["job_ind"] * 100 // (data["job_ind_end"] + 1)

def end_job():
    print("job done")
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(when_new_file)
    is_button_press[0] = False
    data.clear()
    bpy.context.scene.export_progress = -1
    bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()
    

class Progress_test(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.test"
    bl_label = "Progress_test"

    # not possible running in operator using forloop
    # because after running bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile(), operator cannot access, blender will crash
    def execute(self, context):
        if not is_button_press[0]:
            is_button_press[0] = True
            bpy.app.timers.register(init_job)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class TEST_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Item"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        if is_button_press[0]:
            layout.enabled = False
            layout.prop(context.scene, 'export_progress', slider=True)
        else:
            layout.operator("wm.test")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Progress_test)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_PANEL)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.export_progress = bpy.props.IntProperty(name = 'Exporting...', subtype = 'PERCENTAGE', min = -1, soft_min = 0, soft_max = 100, max = 100, default = -1)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Progress_test)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_PANEL)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.export_progress


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

After you testing above script, change the `init_job` and `do_job` function

```
filepath = "..."

def init_job():
    print("init job")
    data["job_ind"] = 0
    data["names"] = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]
    data["job_ind_end"] = len(data["names"]) - 1
    bpy.context.scene.export_progress = 0
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(when_new_file)
    bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()

def do_job():
    print("do_job, ind= ", data["job_ind"])
    
    name = data["names"][data["job_ind"]]
    object = bpy.data.objects[name]
    object.location = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())

    override = bpy.context.copy()
    override['selected_objects'] = [object]
    with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=os.path.join(filepath, f"{object.name}.fbx"), use_selection=True)

    if data["job_ind"] == data["job_ind_end"]:
        end_job()
    else:
        bpy.app.timers.register(next_job)
```

Comment: It works but will it work in a background instance?

Comment: background instance? Do you mean allow the user modify the scene when exporting?

Comment: No, I will run the blender instance in the background using `subprocess.Popon()`. In the background this exporting will happen.

Comment: Not sure, you need test it. I guess it can't because you need wait to restore the file.

Comment: Can you implement the `wait to restore the file` in your answer?

Comment: No idea, As the docs say:  
So far, no work has been done to make Blender’s Python integration thread safe, so until it’s properly supported, it’s best not make use of this.

Note

Python threads only allow concurrency and won’t speed up your scripts on multiprocessor systems, the subprocess and multiprocess modules can be used with Blender to make use of multiple CPUs too.  

https://docs.blender.org/api/3.6/info_gotcha.html

Comment: @Karan Please add all the relevant information in your question at once. It is unfair to the person who responded if you keep adding new conditions to your question. Please post only one question per thread. Also a little bit of gratitude goes a long way to make someone's time worthwile. If you don't know how to express it, you can try just saying "thank you". Cheers

Comment: Sorry, @Gorgious but the 2 questions are related to each other.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that you're only allowed to ask one per thread

Comment: the objects are not in their previous location after export

Comment: I get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karan\Desktop\untitled.blend\Text", line 13, in when_new_file
  File "C:\Users\karan\Desktop\untitled.blend\Text", line 36, in do_job
NameError: name 'context' is not defined`

Comment: change to `bpy.context`. 
From the script, it exports a random location, then restores your saved file and exports a random location again, Did you find that it not restore to the original location?

Comment: If you need keep the location, store the location to a global variable and get it back.

Comment: when we are restoring using `bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()` then why we need to store the location to a global variable?

Comment: still getting `NameError: name 'context' is not defined` error

Comment: I think after `end_job()` it should restore once again.

Comment: yup, I tested it success after this fix